# USAR OR O AND (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Les traigo mi siguiente problema,
tengo que hacer una query que me traiga valores redondos

yo lo pense asi

```
select TransaccionId,EffectiveDate, codigo_comprobante, AccountCode,Cuentas.Description, NetAmount, 
JournalDescription, LineDescription, DocumentType, CreatedDate,nombreApellido_usuario
from TablaPrincipal
left join Cuentas on TablaPrincipal.AccountCode = Cuentas.id_cuenta
left join Movimiento on TablaPrincipal.Id_movimiento = Movimiento.Id_movimiento
left join TiposComprobante on TablaPrincipal.TipoComprobante = TiposComprobante.id_comprobante
left join Usuarios on TablaPrincipal.UserId = Usuarios.Id_usuario
where CreatedDate >= '02/01/2019' and CreatedDate <= '03/01/2019' and
NetAmount = 100 or NetAmount=1000 or NetAmount = 10000 or NetAmount = 100000 or
NetAmount = 200 or NetAmount=2000 or NetAmount = 20000 or NetAmount = 200000 or
NetAmount = 300 or NetAmount=3000 or NetAmount = 30000 or NetAmount = 300000 or
NetAmount = 400 or NetAmount=4000 or NetAmount = 40000 or NetAmount = 400000 or
NetAmount = 500 or NetAmount=5000 or NetAmount = 50000 or NetAmount = 500000 or
NetAmount = 600 or NetAmount=6000 or NetAmount = 60000 or NetAmount = 600000 or
NetAmount = 700 or NetAmount=7000 or NetAmount = 70000 or NetAmount = 700000 or
NetAmount = 800 or NetAmount=8000 or NetAmount = 80000 or NetAmount = 800000 or
NetAmount = 900 or NetAmount=9000 or NetAmount = 90000 or NetAmount = 900000
```

me trae los valores que yo quiero, pero lo que no respeta es el rango de la fecha me sigue trayendo valores redondos que esta por fuera de ese intervalo declarado

ALGUNA SUGERENCIA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes cambiar los operadores

> **OR**

por

> **IN**

```
select TransaccionId,EffectiveDate, codigo_comprobante, AccountCode,Cuentas.Description, NetAmount, 
JournalDescription, LineDescription, DocumentType, CreatedDate,nombreApellido_usuario
from TablaPrincipal
left join Cuentas on TablaPrincipal.AccountCode = Cuentas.id_cuenta
left join Movimiento on TablaPrincipal.Id_movimiento = Movimiento.Id_movimiento
left join TiposComprobante on TablaPrincipal.TipoComprobante = TiposComprobante.id_comprobante
left join Usuarios on TablaPrincipal.UserId = Usuarios.Id_usuario
where (CreatedDate >= '02/01/2019' and CreatedDate <= '03/01/2019') AND
NetAmount IN
(
   100, 1000, 10000, 100000,
   200, 2000, 20000, 200000,
   300, 3000, 30000, 300000,
   400, 4000, 40000, 400000,
   500, 5000, 50000, 500000,
   600, 6000, 60000, 600000,
   700, 7000, 70000, 700000,
   800, 8000, 80000, 800000,
   900, 9000, 90000, 900000
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Te hacen falta los parentesis, debes hacerlo asi:

```
select TransaccionId,EffectiveDate, codigo_comprobante, AccountCode,Cuentas.Description, NetAmount, 
JournalDescription, LineDescription, DocumentType, CreatedDate,nombreApellido_usuario
from TablaPrincipal
left join Cuentas on TablaPrincipal.AccountCode = Cuentas.id_cuenta
left join Movimiento on TablaPrincipal.Id_movimiento = Movimiento.Id_movimiento
left join TiposComprobante on TablaPrincipal.TipoComprobante = TiposComprobante.id_comprobante
left join Usuarios on TablaPrincipal.UserId = Usuarios.Id_usuario
where (CreatedDate >= '02/01/2019' and CreatedDate <= '03/01/2019') and
(NetAmount = 100 or NetAmount=1000 or NetAmount = 10000 or NetAmount = 100000 or
NetAmount = 200 or NetAmount=2000 or NetAmount = 20000 or NetAmount = 200000 or
NetAmount = 300 or NetAmount=3000 or NetAmount = 30000 or NetAmount = 300000 or
NetAmount = 400 or NetAmount=4000 or NetAmount = 40000 or NetAmount = 400000 or
NetAmount = 500 or NetAmount=5000 or NetAmount = 50000 or NetAmount = 500000 or
NetAmount = 600 or NetAmount=6000 or NetAmount = 60000 or NetAmount = 600000 or
NetAmount = 700 or NetAmount=7000 or NetAmount = 70000 or NetAmount = 700000 or
NetAmount = 800 or NetAmount=8000 or NetAmount = 80000 or NetAmount = 800000 or
NetAmount = 900 or NetAmount=9000 or NetAmount = 90000 or NetAmount = 900000)
```

Comment: Buenisimo Funciono!